# Dummy variables for Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression on three factors that are all binary.

My data

```
   table1<-expand.grid(Crime=factor(c("Shoplifting","Other Theft Acts")),Gender=factor(c("Men","Women")),
    Priorconv=factor(c("N","P")))
    table1<-data.frame(table1,Yes=c(24,52,48,22,17,60,15,4),No=c(1,9,3,2,6,34,6,3))
```

and the model

```
fit4<-glm(cbind(Yes,No)~Priorconv+Crime+Priorconv:Crime,data=table1,family=binomial)
summary(fit4)
```

R seems to take 1 for prior conviction P and 1 for crime shoplifting. As a result the interaction effect is only 1 if both of the above are 1. I would now like to try different combinations for the interaction term, for example I would like to see what it would be if prior conviction is P **and** crime is not shoplifting.

Is there a way to make R take different cases for the 1s and the 0s? It would facilitate my analysis greatly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already getting all four combinations of the two categorical variables in your regression. You can see this as follows:

Here's the output of your regression:

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(Yes, No) ~ Priorconv + Crime + Priorconv:Crime, 
    family = binomial, data = table1)

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   1.9062     0.3231   5.899 3.66e-09 ***
PriorconvP                   -1.3582     0.3835  -3.542 0.000398 ***
CrimeShoplifting              0.9842     0.6069   1.622 0.104863    
PriorconvP:CrimeShoplifting  -0.5513     0.7249  -0.761 0.446942
```

So, for `Priorconv`, the reference category (the one with dummy value = 0) is `N`. And for `Crime` the reference category is `Other`. So here's how to interpret the regression results for each of the four possibilities (where log(p/(1-p)) is the log of the odds of a `Yes` result):

```
1. PriorConv = N and Crime = Other. This is just the case where both dummies are 
    zero, so your regression is just the intercept:

log(p/(1-p)) = 1.90

2. PriorConv = P and Crime = Other. So the Priorconv dummy equals 1 and the 
   Crime dummy is still zero:

log(p/(1-p)) = 1.90 - 1.36

3. PriorConv = N and Crime = Shoplifting. So the Priorconv dummy is 0 and the 
   Crime dummy is now 1:

log(p/(1-p)) = 1.90 + 0.98

4. PriorConv = P and Crime = Shoplifting. Now both dummies are 1:

log(p/(1-p)) = 1.90 - 1.36 + 0.98 - 0.55
```

You can reorder the factor values of the two predictor variables, but that will just change which combinations of variables fall into each of the four cases above.

**Update:** Regarding the issue of regression coefficients relative to ordering of the factors. Changing the reference level will change the coefficients, because the coefficients will represent contrasts between different combinations of categories, but it won't change the predicted probabilities of a `Yes` or `No` outcome. (Regression modeling wouldn't be all that credible if you could change the predictions just by changing the reference category.) Note, for example, that the predicted probabilities are the same even if we switch the reference category for `Priorconv`:

```
m1 = glm(cbind(Yes,No)~Priorconv+Crime+Priorconv:Crime,data=table1,family=binomial)
predict(m1, type="response")

1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.9473684 0.8705882 0.9473684 0.8705882 0.7272727 0.6336634 0.7272727 0.6336634 

table2 = table1
table2$Priorconv = relevel(table2$Priorconv, ref = "P")

m2 = glm(cbind(Yes,No)~Priorconv+Crime+Priorconv:Crime,data=table2,family=binomial)
predict(m2, type="response")

1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.9473684 0.8705882 0.9473684 0.8705882 0.7272727 0.6336634 0.7272727 0.6336634
```

Comment: The main source of confusion here is the interaction term I am afraid. If it had been that we set CrimeOther to 1 and PriorConvP also to 1, wouldn't it be different, perhaps even significant?

Comment: @JohnK In this case, the p-value will not change since there is only one coefficient associated with the interaction (due to both predictors being binary). In general (predictors have >= 2 levels), if you are interested in testing for an interaction you should do an omnibus test (using `anova()`).

Comment: @DMC The model overall does change slightly for different reference categories. Try for example with this code levels(table1$Crime)
table1$Crime<-relevel(table1$Crime,ref="Shoplifting")
levels(table1$Crime)
table1$Priorconv<-relevel(table1$Priorconv,ref="N")
m<-glm(cbind(Yes,No)~Priorconv*Crime,data=table1,family=binomial)
summary(m)

Comment: @JohnK I was referring to the "significant" in your first comment. The coefficients will certainly change (different parameterizations lead to different comparisons). But the p-value doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the interpretation provided by @eipi10. You can also use `relevel` to change the reference level before fitting the model:

```
levels(table1$Priorconv)
## [1] "N" "P"

table1$Priorconv <- relevel(table1$Priorconv, ref = "P")
levels(table1$Priorconv)
## [1] "P" "N"

m <- glm(cbind(Yes, No) ~ Priorconv*Crime, data = table1, family = binomial)
summary(m)
```

Note that I changed the `formula` argument of `glm()` to include `Priorconv*Crime` which is more compact.