# `lm` summary not display all factor levels

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, r-faq

I am running a linear regression on a number of attributes including two categorical attributes, `B` and `F`, and I don't get a coefficient value for every factor level I have.

`B` has 9 levels and `F` has 6 levels. When I initially ran the model (with intercepts), I got 8 coefficients for `B` and 5 for `F` which I understood as the first level of each being included in the intercept.

I want ranking the levels within `B` and `F` based on their coefficient so I added `-1` after each factor to lock the intercept at 0 so that I could get coefficients for all levels.

```
Call:
lm(formula = dependent ~ a + B-1 + c + d + e + F-1 + g + h, data = input)

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a     2.082e+03  1.026e+02  20.302  < 2e-16 ***
B1   -1.660e+04  9.747e+02 -17.027  < 2e-16 ***
B2   -1.681e+04  9.379e+02 -17.920  < 2e-16 ***
B3   -1.653e+04  9.254e+02 -17.858  < 2e-16 ***
B4   -1.765e+04  9.697e+02 -18.202  < 2e-16 ***
B5   -1.535e+04  1.388e+03 -11.059  < 2e-16 ***
B6   -1.677e+04  9.891e+02 -16.954  < 2e-16 ***
B7   -1.644e+04  9.694e+02 -16.961  < 2e-16 ***
B8   -1.931e+04  9.899e+02 -19.512  < 2e-16 ***
B9   -1.722e+04  9.071e+02 -18.980  < 2e-16 ***
c    -6.928e-01  6.977e-01  -0.993 0.321272    
d    -3.288e-01  2.613e+00  -0.126 0.899933    
e    -8.384e-01  1.171e+00  -0.716 0.474396    
F2    4.679e+02  2.176e+02   2.150 0.032146 *  
F3    7.753e+02  2.035e+02   3.810 0.000159 ***
F4    1.885e+02  1.689e+02   1.116 0.265046    
F5    5.194e+02  2.264e+02   2.295 0.022246 *  
F6    1.365e+03  2.334e+02   5.848 9.94e-09 ***
g     4.278e+00  7.350e+00   0.582 0.560847    
h     2.717e-02  5.100e-03   5.328 1.62e-07 ***
```

**This worked in part, leading to the display of all levels of `B`, however `F1` is still not displayed. As there is no longer an intercept I am confused why `F1` is not in the linear model.**

**Switching the order of the call so that `+ F - 1` precedes `+ B - 1` results in coefficients of all levels of `F` being visible but not `B1`.**

Does anybody know either how to display all levels of both `B` and `F`, or how to assess the relative weight of `F1` compared to other levels of `F` from the outputs I have?

Comment: Zheyuan Li produces a very response to simply say that linear regression is sort of an orthogonal projection of your original function onto a set of simpler functions, your variables. If two (or more) variables are the same (for instance constant functions) only one is kept. And it seems like `R` keeps only the first appearing

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This issue is raised over and over again, but unfortunately no satisfying answer has been made which can be an appropriate duplicate target. Looks like I need to write one.

---

Most people know this is related to "contrasts", but not everyone knows why it is needed, and how to understand its result. We have to look at **model matrix** in order to fully digest this.

Suppose we are interested in a model with two factors: `~ f + g` (numerical covariates do not matter so I include none of them; the response does not appear in model matrix, so drop it, too). Consider the following reproducible example:

```
set.seed(0)

f <- sample(gl(3, 4, labels = letters[1:3]))
# [1] c a a b b a c b c b a c
#Levels: a b c

g <- sample(gl(3, 4, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
# [1] A B A B C B C A C C A B
#Levels: A B C
```

We start with a model matrix with no contrasts at all:

```
X0 <- model.matrix(~ f + g, contrasts.arg = list(
                   f = contr.treatment(n = 3, contrasts = FALSE),
                   g = contr.treatment(n = 3, contrasts = FALSE)))

#   (Intercept) f1 f2 f3 g1 g2 g3
#1            1  0  0  1  1  0  0
#2            1  1  0  0  0  1  0
#3            1  1  0  0  1  0  0
#4            1  0  1  0  0  1  0
#5            1  0  1  0  0  0  1
#6            1  1  0  0  0  1  0
#7            1  0  0  1  0  0  1
#8            1  0  1  0  1  0  0
#9            1  0  0  1  0  0  1
#10           1  0  1  0  0  0  1
#11           1  1  0  0  1  0  0
#12           1  0  0  1  0  1  0
```

Note, we have:

```
unname( rowSums(X0[, c("f1", "f2", "f3")]) )
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

unname( rowSums(X0[, c("g1", "g2", "g3")]) ) 
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

So `span{f1, f2, f3} = span{g1, g2, g3} = span{(Intercept)}`. **In this full specification, 2 columns are not identifiable. `X0` will have column rank `1 + 3 + 3 - 2 = 5`**:

```
qr(X0)$rank
# [1] 5
```

So, if we fit a linear model with this `X0`, 2 coefficients out of 7 parameters will be `NA`:

```
y <- rnorm(12)  ## random `y` as a response
lm(y ~ X - 1)  ## drop intercept as `X` has intercept already

#X0(Intercept)           X0f1           X0f2           X0f3           X0g1  
#      0.32118        0.05039       -0.22184             NA       -0.92868  
#         X0g2           X0g3  
#     -0.48809             NA
```

**What this really implies, is that we have to add 2 linear constraints on 7 parameters, in order to get a full rank model. It does not really matter what these 2 constraints are, but there must be 2 linearly independent constrains.** For example, we can do either of the following:

- drop any 2 columns from `X0`;
- add two sum-to-zero constrains on parameters, like we require coefficients for `f1`, `f2` and `f3` sum to 0, and the same for `g1`, `g2` and `g3`.
- use regularization, for example, adding ridge penalty to `f` and `g`.

Note, these three ways end up with three different solutions:

- contrasts;
- constrained least squares;
- linear mixed models or penalized least squares.

The first two are still in the scope of fixed effect modelling. By "contrasts", we reduce the number of parameters until we get a full rank model matrix; while the other two does not reduce the number of parameters, but effectively reduces the effective degree of freedom.

---

Now, you are certainly after the "contrasts" way. So, remember, we have to drop 2 columns. They can be

- one column from `f` and one column from `g`, giving to a model `~ f + g`, with `f` and `g` contrasted;
- intercept, and one column from either `f` or `g`, giving to a model `~ f + g - 1`.

Now you should be clear, that within the framework of dropping columns, there is no way you can get what you want, because you are expecting to drop only 1 column. The resulting model matrix will still be rank-deficient.

If you really want to have all coefficients there, use constrained least squares, or penalized regression / linear mixed models.

---

Now, when we have interaction of factors, things are more complicated but the idea is still the same. But given that my answer is already long enough, I don't want to continue.

Comment: Thank you Zheyuan for such a detailed explanation! I now understand why I cannot get away with just dropping one column (the intercept) using this method. I will look into the options you suggested to find the one most appropriate to my data :)

Comment: `lm(y ~ X - 1)` - supposed to be `lm(y ~ X0 - 1)`?

Comment: I definitely have to bookmark this answer -- I keep not finding it when I need it ...