# Why am I losing categorical data in my regression summary?

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

```
box <- read.csv("BlackBoxtrainApril22.csv")

#Change the 2 categorical variables into factors
box$SOUND <- as.factor(box$SOUND)
box$SWITCH <- as.factor(box$SWITCH)

#divide training and testing data
train <- box[1:12000,]
test <- box[12001:18048,]

library(nnet)
require(nnet)
multinom_model <- multinom(SOUND ~ ., data=box)
summary(multinom_model)
```

Here's some output from `dput(head(box))` to see what the data looks like:

```r
structure(list(ID = c(86623L, 57936L, 54301L, 2678L, 65827L, 22420L), INPUT1 = c(30L, 87L, 16L, 64L, 33L, 5L), INPUT2 = c(31L, 76L, 33L, 77L, 72L, 50L), INPUT3 = c(72L, 31L, 87L, 91L, 53L, 26L), INPUT4 = c(29L, 79L, 41L, 59L, 66L, 50L), SWITCH = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Minimum", "High", "High"), SOUND = c("Gargle", "Tick", "Tick", "Beep", "Beep", "Gargle")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In essence, I'm trying to predict a categorical variable using a combination of numeric and categorical data.
This is my code. When I do a summary, I lose one of the `SWITCH` categories and one of `SOUND` categories.
I think it has something to do with reference variables, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Welcome to SO, AriMorrison! Realize that we have no idea what is in the data, so it's unlikely we can help at all. Please provide a sample of the data by posting the output from `dput(head(box))`; if there are a lot of columns, then perhaps `dput(box[1:10,1:5])` or some specific subset of rows and columns that well-represents the data. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good examples on asking questions in a reproducible way.

Comment: Thanks. It's my first time posting on SO, so appologies for that.  Here's the output from dput(head(box)):  structure(list(ID = c(86623L, 57936L, 54301L, 2678L, 65827L, 
22420L), INPUT1 = c(30L, 87L, 16L, 64L, 33L, 5L), INPUT2 = c(31L, 
76L, 33L, 77L, 72L, 50L), INPUT3 = c(72L, 31L, 87L, 91L, 53L, 
26L), INPUT4 = c(29L, 79L, 41L, 59L, 66L, 50L), SWITCH = c("Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Minimum", "High", "High"), SOUND = c("Gargle", 
"Tick", "Tick", "Beep", "Beep", "Gargle")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: (Please [edit] your question and put it there, don't post it in a comment. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the reference categories. When you include a categorical/factor variable in a model, one category of the variable is always excluded and serves as the reference category. The estimates for the categories that you ***do*** see in the output are in reference to the category that was excluded. For example, if you have a factor variable with categories "red", "blue", and "green", and "red" is the reference category, then the model estimates for "blue" and "green" will be for "blue" vs "red" and "green" vs "red", respectively.

Comment: this should be a FAQ ... anyone know how to find the appropriate duplicates easily?

Comment: @BenBolker I closed a similar question earlier today with [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032858/lm-summary-not-display-all-factor-levels), but I seem to remember seeing a less technical answer somewhere else