# Why is one of my control variables not showing up in my regression table?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am using R on panel data to get a regression table. One of my control variables is not showing up in my regression table (namely: SPINDEX).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
 # Descriptives and tables

#descriptive 1
dfOnlyInteresting = select(df, "amountAquired", "NumberDirectors", "AnnualReportDate", "GenderRatio", "AGE", "roa", "xrd", "SPINDEX", "aquisitionFin", "aqusitionsNot0", "CEOTenure", "compRatio", "laggedAquisition", "amountAquired_mean")
stargazer(dfOnlyInteresting, type = "html", title="Descriptive statistics", digits=1, out="descriptives.doc")

# Create a panel dataframe
df.p = pdata.frame(df, index = c("GVKEY" ,"AnnualReportDate"))

# Test for duplicate row names
occur = data.frame(table(row.names(df.p)))
duplicateRowNames = occur[occur$Freq > 1,]

# Table 2
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Define models
#----------------------------------------------------------
mdlA <- amountAquired ~ GenderRatio + CEOTenure + AGE + roa + factor(SPINDEX) + aquisitionFin + xrd + laggedAquisition
mdlB <- amountAquired ~ GenderRatio + CEOTenure + AGE + roa + factor(SPINDEX) + aquisitionFin + xrd + laggedAquisition + compRatio
mdlC <- amountAquired ~ GenderRatio + CEOTenure + AGE + roa + factor(SPINDEX) + aquisitionFin + xrd + laggedAquisition + compRatio*NumberDirectors + compRatio
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309639/why-am-i-losing-categorical-data-in-my-regression-summary

Comment: If `SPINDEX` is a factor with only 2 or three levels, it could be predicted by knowing other discrete variables in the model. In such an instance, R will detect what are called "aliased" variables and omit them from the model. If that wasn't done, then the matrix algebra would fail.

Comment: @JonSpring that thread referred to one variable being dropped within a categorical variable (i.e.: for "colors" as a control variable, blue was dropped). But my control variable "SPINDEX" does not even show up in the regression table

Comment: @IRTFM  It has 9 levels so I am not sure why its being dropped

Comment: This is difficult to answer without a reproducible example but to me this almost always happens because of collinearity which the other comments point to. Also, if you use factor() your output will, depending on the regression command/package your using, not return SPINDEX but its factor realization or something like as.factor(SPINDEX)Realization

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can still experience multicollinearity with 9 levels.