# How to build a lmer model with these data?

Tags: r, linearmodels

I was asked to build a mixed effect model using 'lmer' and 'lmerTest'. The data is shown below:
[image: First 8 rows of the data, it's about how pollination, herbivory and plant defense(HCN) may alter flower traits]

The full Question is :
"Use the `lme4` and `lmerTest` R packages to run a linear mixed-effects model examining how herbivores (`Herbivory`), pollinators (`Pollination`), plant defences (`HCN`) *and all interactions* influence the length of banner petals (`Avg.Bnr.Wdth`) produced by plants while accounting for variation due to spatial block and plant genotype. Allow the intercept for `Genotype` to vary across the levels of the herbivory treatment (Hint: are `Genotype` and `Herbivory` crossed or nested?)"

My attempt to build a model:

```
model_2a <- lmer(data = plant_data, Avg.Bnr.Wdth ~ Herbivory * Pollination +
                   Herbivory * HCN +
                   Pollination * HCN +
                   (1|Block) +
                   (1|Genotype))
summary(model_2a)
```

However, the output is odd:

```
Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.7400 -0.5967  0.0692  0.6326  3.2019 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Genotype (Intercept) 0.068569 0.2619  
 Block    (Intercept) 0.003272 0.0572  
 Residual             0.046580 0.2158  
Number of obs: 595, groups:  Genotype, 49; Block, 6

Fixed effects:
                                   Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        3.270378   0.062366  58.163245  52.438   <2e-16 ***
HerbivoryReduced                   0.005644   0.031429 540.971084   0.180   0.8575    
PollinationSupp                   -0.051416   0.031547 538.253166  -1.630   0.1037    
HCNYes                            -0.110019   0.081633  58.795573  -1.348   0.1829    
HerbivoryReduced:PollinationSupp   0.013405   0.036148 539.473352   0.371   0.7109    
HerbivoryReduced:HCNYes            0.062927   0.036135 539.454401   1.741   0.0822 .  
PollinationSupp:HCNYes             0.071009   0.035959 539.235883   1.975   0.0488 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) HrbvrR PllntS HCNYes HrR:PS HR:HCN
HerbvryRdcd -0.262                                   
PollintnSpp -0.246  0.328                            
HCNYes      -0.640  0.132  0.117                     
HrbvryRd:PS  0.150 -0.589 -0.609  0.001              
HrbvrR:HCNY  0.156 -0.581  0.012 -0.241  0.022       
PllntS:HCNY  0.133  0.038 -0.536 -0.214 -0.021 -0.036
```

First. I have no idea how to "vary the Genotype intercept across the Herbivory treatment."

Second. Why it's "HerbivoryReduced","PollinationSupp" in the output, I tried to `as.factor` Pollination, Herbivory and HCN, but it still shows the same thing

Comment: is the only thing that's "odd" about the output the appearance of "HerbivoryReduced","PollinationSupp" in the output? This is part of the standard behaviour of linear models in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032858/lm-summary-not-display-all-factor-levels

Comment: I mean, "Herbivory," "Pollination" and "HCN" all have more than one level (e.g. ambient vs. reduced on Herbivory), I wonder what happened to other levels

Comment: Did you read the link in my comment?