# Finalfit output in R Studio is not displaying p value?

Tags: r

I'm a student learning on R studio. I'm using the finalfit function to explore potential relationships between variables of interest, but I am running into an issue that I cannot seem to figure out for the life of me. When I run the code chunk, I'm not seeing a p value for the "Strongly Disagree" response:

[image: Finalfit Output]

This is my code chunk:

```
library(finalfit)
explanatory = c( "Belief_No_Change_Feedback_rc" )
dependent = "Investigate_Renewal_rc"
df %>%
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory, metrics=TRUE,  cont = "median", na_include = FALSE,  
           column = TRUE, total_col = TRUE, add_dependent_label = TRUE, dependent_label_prefix = "Dependent: ",       digits=c(3,2,3,3,2,3) ) -> r6
tab_df( r6[[1]], footnote= r6[[2]], show.footnote = TRUE)
```

What would be the reason for this problem and how can I begin to fix it?

Kind regards,

A Frustrated Student

- I've looked back at my recoding steps; did not identify any obvious issues.
- Investigated FinalFit code chunk for any issues. None found.
- Scoured the depths of the internet to no avail.

Comment: Hello E. E.S, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. Specifically include some data so people who respond can produce a working tested answer. You'll receive better help faster that way.

Comment: My guess is that this is related to [a common question about linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032858/lm-summary-not-display-all-factor-levels): "Strongly Disagree" is the reference level to which the other levels are compared, so it does not have a coefficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community The problem is the questioner's lack of statistical background. neilfws accurately described the problem